# "things are going great with something" or "things are going great in something"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please which sentence is correct.

> Things are going great **with** the company, so the workers are going to have a pay rise.
>
> Things are going great **in** the company, so the workers are going to have a pay rise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between IN and WITH](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122442/difference-between-in-and-with)

Comment: Both prepositions are fine with referents like ***company, school, club***, etc., as is ***at***. That's not the case with all similar referents. For example, ***home*** only really accepts ***at***, and the same normally applies to ***work*** - but at least some people will also be happy with *Things are going well **with** work*.